# Run pylint for both python 2.7 and 3.7, in pre-commit hook on Docker image

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit.com

I am trying to use CircleCI to run a pre-commit hook that runs pylint for both Python 2.7 and 3.7.

`.circleci/config.yml` runs pre-commit for both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
jobs:
  lint-py2:
    docker:
      - image: python:2.7.14
    steps:
      {snip}
      - run: pre-commit run --all-files
      {snip}

  lint-py3:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.7.3
    steps:
      {snip}
      - run: pre-commit run --all-files
      {snip}
```

pre-commit, among other things, runs pylint:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-pylint
    rev: v2.3.1  # Which version here?
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
```

The problem here is that [there is no version of pylint that is compatible with both Python 2.7 and 3.7](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2572): Python 2.7 requires pylint 1.x and Python 3.7 requires pylint 2.x.

How can I make Circle CI run both linting jobs using different versions of pylint?

I am considering several options:

- Add pylint twice in the pre-commit configuration (with different aliases) and [disable](https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks) one or the other in the job definition

  - It seems that pre-commit tries to install dependencies *before* looking at the `SKIP` variable, so the Python 2.7 run tries to install pylint 2 anyway, and errors with `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint==2.3.1 (from pre-commit-dummy-package==0.0.0)`
- Use a Docker image that has both Python versions and [set the python version](https://pre-commit.com/#overriding-language-version) at the hook level

  - This requires building my own Docker image
- Skip pylint in one of the linting jobs
- Drop 2.7 or 3.7 support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option is probably to install both python2 and python3 though it is possible to use multiple configuration files to accomplish what you want:

Another option would be to only run one of them during CI by utilizing the [`--config`](https://pre-commit.com/#cli) option

With this you would have your default `.pre-commit-config.yaml` and a special `.pre-commit-config-py27.yaml` which includes the python2.7 pylint instead of the python3 pylint

In CI you'd invoke `pre-commit run --config .pre-commit-config-py27.yaml --all-files --show-diff-on-failure` for python2.7 and the normal `pre-commit run --all-files --show-diff-on-failure` for the non-py27 run